# mysql regular expression search string with numeric dash

Tags: mysql, regex

please help write a regular expression to for the following strings.

I have in database the following values

```
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2-2
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2-3
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-3
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1.ans1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1-1.ans1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2.ans1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2.ans2
```

I want to pull only the following records:

```
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2-2
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2-3
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-3
```

I use

```
^results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

that pull me

```
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-3
```

How to change the expression to pull the desired result ?

**EDIT**

one additional case:

need reg expression for

```
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1-1.id
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-2.text
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-3-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.person-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.person-1-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.person-2
```

the result should be

```
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-3-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.person-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.person-1-1
results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.person-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^results.dr_phil_app_progress._tapes.data.exercise-([0-9-]*)$
```

Here is the working [EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/jD6oL6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You forget the hyphen and also you should escape the dots.,

```
"^results\\.dr_phil_app_progress\\._tapes\\.data\\.exercise-([0-9]|[1-9]-[0-9])$"
```

Comment: this will only match one or two part numbers. and the numbrs must be 1 digit only to match

Comment: how to match, let say: exercise-1034-678

Comment: `exercise-([0-9]+|[1-9]+-[0-9]+)$`

Answer (score 0):

```
NOT REGEXP '[.]ans'
```

That should work on the set you provided.  If that is not good enough for the entire list, then be more precise.